# hive on spark - why doesn't 'select *' spawn spark app/executors?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql

I have setup Hive (v2.3.4) on Spark (exec engine).

This launches a spark app/executors:

```
select count(*) from s.t where h_code = 'KGD78' and h_no = '265'
```

Why doesn't this launch a spark app/executors:

```
select * from s.t where h_code = 'KGD78' and h_no = '265'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This - the 2nd case - is due to the not so well-known **"hive.fetch.task.conversion"** parameter.

Depending on how set, Hive can launch a single **"fetch task"** instead of a Map Reduce job even with a filter i.e. where clause.

If you select * or a non-partitioned column it will launch a fetch task instead of an MR-job - single thread. Single thread is not always a good thing. The count(*) should speak for itself, you need to a lot of processing potentially, the second case can be seen like a cursor.

You can change parameter to "minimal" or "none" in hive-site.xml to obviate this type of processing.

Well spotted.